# Find all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2 + y^2 =3(2023)^z +77$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

The question says **Do not use any modular arithmetic.**

**My attempt:**

First of all i think that these two things would help:

> If $4 \mid x^2 + y^2 \implies 2\mid x$ And $y$. **I’ve proved this one**

> If $7 \mid x^2 + y^2 \implies 7 \mid x$ And y. **I don’t know how to prove this.**

And it turns out that the only possible values to $(x,y,z)=(4,8,0)$.

Comment: By the way, I think it's a bit strange restriction (especially if you are allowed using divisibility but not modular arithmetic!).

Comment: $(x,y,z)=(4,8,0)$ is not a solution as z is natural number

Comment: $0$ Is a natural number by the way @AsherAbraham

Comment: @Yassir $0$ is not a natural number

Comment: When i talk about positive integers i use $ \mathbb{N}^*$ @AsherAbraham

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write $x=7k+r$ where $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ so $$x^2 = 7(7k^2+2kr)+r^2$$ so $$x^2 = 7k'+r^2$$
Similary we have $$y^2 = 7l'+r'^2$$

Since $7\mid x^2+y^2$ we have now $$7\mid r^2+ r'^2$$

but this is possible only if $r=r'=0$ i.e. $7\mid x$ and $7\mid y$.

---

> We see that if right side is divisible by 7 so $7\mid x$ and $7\mid y$ so $49$ divides RHS but that mean that $49\mid 7$ if $z\geq 2$. So $z\leq 1$. Can you finish now?

Comment: I didn’t understand you ‘Spoiler’. How can $49 \mid 7$ ?

Comment: That can not be so z=<1

Comment: What is the relation between : $z\geq 2$ And $49 \mid 7$

Comment: If $z\geq 2$ then $49\mid 3(2023)^z$, else that is not true.

Comment: But in the case $z=1$ There is no solution . Because $4 \mid x^2 + y^2$ But $4\nmid 6146$ .

Comment: Ok..............